# How can I run powershell in the background if I want execution policy Bypass?

Tags: powershell

I have this batch file which runs the powershell script.

I want to run it the background but if I run with "windowstyle hidden" still visible.

powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -windowstyle hidden -File "C:\script.ps1"

Comment: you could add this as a scheduled task and start the scheduled task from within your batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run, e.g. long running scripts, as a jobs.

To start it you run

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}
```

this will start the `Get-Process` cmdlet in the background. The script can be also some custom made script or a longer script, it doesn't need to be a one-liner.

You can check its status by running

```
$job | Get-Job
```

and to receive the output you run

```
$job | Receive-Job
```

just note that once the data is received, it's lost. You can only receive it once, after that it's up to you to save it in a variable or later processing.

Finally to remove the job from the queue you run

```
$job | Remove-Job
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function:

```
function bg() {
  Start-Process `
   -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location) `
   -NoNewWindow `
   -FilePath "powershell" `
   -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -command `"$args`" " 
}
```

It starts a new powershell instance which is executed in background and allows the usage of cmdlets.
You call it like:

```
bg "Start-Sleep 2; get-location; write 'done' "
```